# similar_text - string / integer comparing

Tags: php, string, integer, type-conversion, similarity

it's my first post here, so welcome everyone!

I'm trying to write a rule to simply protect my website against flooding by users posting it's content. I decided to use [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function in PHP to compare strings (last added string by user and the one that one is adding at the moment), calculate similarity (%) and if the result is too high (similar in more than 90%) the script will not add a record to database.

Here is what I have:

```
similar_text($last_record, $new_record, $sim);
$similarity = (int) number_format($sim, 0);

if ($similarity < 90)
{
  // add the record
}
else
{
  // dont add anything
}
```

The problem is with this: **if ($similarity < 90)**. I format the number and then convert it from string to int value, but the script doesn't care.

When I use quotas it works: **if ($similarity < "90")**. The question is why script doesn't work when I use the value as an integer value and it works when I use it as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) returns a string where you need an int.  So a string comparison to "90" works, but an int comparison fails.  You can use [`int_val`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to convert to an int.

Also, I'm wondering if maybe you have something else wrong.  I took your code sample and ran it locally, and it seems to work just fine even without swapping `(int)` for `int_val`.

With the following values:

```
$last_record = "asdfasdfasdf";
$new_record = "aasdfasdfasdf";
```

`$similarity` is `96` and the greater than section of the if triggers.

With these values:

```
$last_record = "asdfasdfasdf";
$new_record = "fffdfasdfasdf";
```

`$similarity` is `80` and the less than section of the if triggers.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
It's weird in fact. I check `$similarity` using `var_dump()` function and it says that `$similarity` is integer.

Comment: Very weird. Maybe it was just a fluke. If you'd accept my answer, I'd appreciate it. :)